# UWP create database with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm trying to create a database and its tables using SQLite in my UWP app. My code doesn't give me any error, but I can't find my database file.

```
SqliteEngine.UseWinSqlite3(); //Configuring library to use SDK version of SQLite
        using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=sqliteSample.db"))
        {
            db.Open();
            // Resume Table
            String resumeTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Resume (resumeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, educationInfoId INTEGER NULL, personalInfoId INTEGER NULL, userId INTEGER, certInfoId INTEGER NULL, workInfoId INTEGER NULL)";
            SqliteCommand createResumeTable = new SqliteCommand(resumeTable, db);

            // PersonalInfo Table
            String personalInfoTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PersonalInfo (personalInfoId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userId INTEGER, city VARCHAR(100) NULL, email VARCHAR(50) NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NULL, state VARCHAR(10) NULL)";
            SqliteCommand createPersonalInfoTable = new SqliteCommand(personalInfoTable, db);
            try
            {
                createResumeTable.ExecuteReader();
                createPersonalInfoTable.ExecuteReader();
            }
            catch (SqliteException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Is something wrong in the code? Where should the database file be?

Thanks

Comment: The database is in the directory that you have specified in the connection string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SqlitePCL in nuget. http://sqlite.org/download.html

The download page have UAP softward that you should download it.

The download file is VSIX that you should install it.

Open Tools -> Extensions and Updates… -> Installed -> SDKs can see

[image]

Restart visual studio and right click your project `References –> Add Reference`
and add sqlite

[image]

Open nuget search SQLitePCL.

[image]

There are some sql string

```
    private static String DB_NAME = "SQLiteSample.db";
    private static String TABLE_NAME = "SampleTable";
    private static String SQL_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (Key TEXT,Value TEXT);";
    private static String SQL_QUERY_VALUE = "SELECT Value FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE Key = (?);";
    private static String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES(?,?);";


    private static String SQL_UPDATE = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET Value = ? WHERE Key = ?";
    private static String SQL_DELETE = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE Key = ?"
```

Creat table

```
_connection = new SQLiteConnection(DB_NAME);
using (var statement = _connection.Prepare(SQL_CREATE_TABLE))
{
    statement.Step();
}
```

INSERT

```
using (var statement = _connection.Prepare(SQL_INSERT))
{
    statement.Bind(1, key);
    statement.Bind(2, value);
    statement.Step();
}
```

DELETE

```
using (var statement = _connection.Prepare(SQL_DELETE))
{
    statement.Bind(1, key);
    statement.Step();
}
```

UPDATE

```
using(var statement = _connection.Prepare(SQL_UPDATE))
{
    statement.Bind(1, value);
    statement.Bind(2, key);
    statement.Step();
}
```

See http://www.cnblogs.com/ms-uap/p/4798269.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the code is correct. I just verified.

Unless you have done something custom, the default location should be:

C:\Users\"**Your User Name**"\AppData\Local\Packages\"**Your App Package**"\LocalState\sqliteSample.db

Answer (score 0):

1. Download SQLite for Universal App Platform Extension -> add ref.
2. Install nuget pack - SQLite.Net-PCL.

>

```
private static string dbPath = string.Empty;
    private static string DBPath(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath))
        {
            dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, fileName);
        }
        return dbPath;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Get fileName From LocalFolder. Please Create first a dataBase.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static SQLiteConnection DbConnection(string fileName)
    {
        return new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DBPath(fileName));
    }
```